# Import js code in node

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

I'm using Drupal 7 and Clean theme. And i have got a map. That's javascript codes. I created map field in my content type and want import this javascript in node.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[hook_node_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) will make sure that a node is being prepared for edit before to be rendered for view.

e.g.

```
function MODULE_node_view_alter(&$build){
   $build['mymap'] = array(
       '#markup' => 'Your JS Code',
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use hook_node_view_alter() and [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

```
drupal_add_js('path/to/file.js', 'file');
```